# Deployment error in node application in service fabric ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-16.04, azure-service-fabric, azure-cli

this is my first time working in Microsoft framework azure.

I got **Ubuntu 16.04** environment and I have packaged a node app using `yeoman` as given in Microsoft document.

Also, I have created a cluster successfully on azure resource group and now when I am trying to deploy my node application on that it is throwing error

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-quickstart-containers-linux

Error I am getting is

`UserWarning: sfctl has version "7.1.0" which does not match the cluster version "6.5.460.1". See https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cli#service-fabric-target-runtime for version compatibility. Upgrade to a compatible version for the best experience`

How can I update the cluster version  or downgrade `sfctl` version ? I followed the link but not getting it exactly. Little help will be appreciated

**EDIT:-**

After downgrading my `sfctl` verion to 6.0.0 , the error has been removed.
But after completion of my installation an error has been thrown.

`Error occurred in request., RetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool (host='url',port:''):Max retry exceeded ......`

Connection error is 504